# Number guessing game that requires suggestions for completion

Tags: python-3.x

how do I get the difficulty level to work? I have found other codes similar but the difficulty is based on the group of number that it will choose the number from i.e. easy(1,10), medium (1,50), hard (1,100). I need to know how to make it work for the number of guesses. It keeps telling me I don't have easy,medium, or hard defined. how do I define them in way to make this code work?
I can get through it asking for my name then it will ask for the difficulty level and when I type e,m,or,h this is what it gives me: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\ajohn\OneDrive - Fairmont State University\BISM3800\Assign2.py", line 58, in  guesses = get_guesses(level) File "C:\Users\ajohn\OneDrive - Fairmont State University\BISM3800\Assign2.py", line 50, in get_guesses if diffuculty == hard: NameError: name 'diffuculty' is not defined

here is the objectives for the code:

You are to ask the user if they wish to play the game or continue playing the game after they have guessed the number

You are to ask the user if they want easy, medium or HARD (Easy = unlimited guesses, Medium = 10 guesses, HARD = 5 guesses)

Once the game begins play you are to tell the user that you have picked a number and they are to guess what that number is

your application is to accept the players guess and if their guess is larger than the number you had picked then tell them that, if their guess is smaller then tell them that as well.

The game continues to play until the player picks the number you had originally picked or they have ran out of guesses. I also need to have an exception.

Here is my code so far:

## This is a guessing the number game.

import random

## this statement will allow the options for playing and quiting the game.

play = True

while play:

```
difficulty = 0

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name?')

myName = input()

easy = random.randint (1,100)
easy = random.randint (1,100)
easy = random.randint (1,100)
```

## prompts the user to select a difficulty to play on

```
def select_level():    
    while True:
        level = str(input("Would you like to play on easy, medium, or hard? \n"
                      "Type 'e' for easy, 'm' for medium, or 'h' for hard!\n"))
        if level != "e" and level != "m" and level != "h":
            print("Invalid input!\n")
        if level == "e" or level == "m" or level == "h":
            break
    return level
```

## function that prompts the user to guess depending on chosen difficulty

```
def guess_number(level):        
    if level == "e":
        (easy == 500)
    if level == "m":
        (medium == 10)
    if level == "h":
        (hard == 5)
    return guesses
```

## selects number of guesses depending on difficulty selected

```
def get_guesses(level):                  
        if difficulty == easy:
            print ("Okay, " + myName + ". You have unlimited guesses")
        if difficulty == medium:
            print ("Okay, " + myName + ". You have 10 guesses.")
        if diffuculty == hard:
            print ("Okay, " + myName + ". You have 5 guesses.")
        elif level != "e" and level != "m" and level != "h":
            print ("Invalid input!")
            get_guesses()
        return guesses

level = select_level()
guesses = get_guesses(level)

print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number can you guess it?')


while guessesTaken < level:
     print('Take a guess.') 
     guess = input()
     guess = int(guess)

     guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

     if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.') 

     if guess > number:
         print('Your guess is too high.')

     if guess == number:
         break


if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
    print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed the number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')

if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)

count=1
again=str(input("Do you want to play again, type yes or no "))
if again == "no":
  play = False
```

Comment: What's your question here?

Comment: how do I get the difficulty level to work? I have found other codes similar but the difficulty is based on the group of number that it will choose the number from i.e. easy(1,10), medium (1,50), hard (1,100). I need to know how to make it work for the number of guesses. It keeps telling me I don't have easy,medium, or hard defined. how do I define them in way to make this code work?

Comment: Hi alicia, where is your error occurring? When you say "I don't have easy, medium, or hard defined," that sounds like you are trying to use the variables `easy`, `medium`, and `hard` before you define them.

Comment: Well, you don't have medium or hard defined. You define ```easy``` three times.
```easy = random.randint (1,100)```

Comment: I can get through it asking for my name then it will ask for the difficulty level and when I type e,m,or,h this is what it gives me: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ajohn\OneDrive - Fairmont State University\BISM3800\Assign2.py", line 58, in <module>
    guesses = get_guesses(level)
  File "C:\Users\ajohn\OneDrive - Fairmont State University\BISM3800\Assign2.py", line 50, in get_guesses
    if diffuculty == hard:
NameError: name 'diffuculty' is not defined

Comment: You have a typo there. ```difficulty``` instead of ```diffuculty```

Comment: @aliciajohnson, please update your question with the further explanations you provided in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Here's the object oriented approach :

```
from random import randint

class Guessing_Game () :
    def __init__ (self, users_name) :
        self.difficulty = 10
        self.name = users_name
        self.start_the_game ()

    def start_the_game (self) :
        my_secret_number = randint (1, self.difficulty)
        print ('Well, ' + self.name + ', I am thinking of a ', end = '')
        print ('between 1 and ' + str (self.difficulty) + '.')
        print ('Can you guess it?')
        self.guess_the_number (my_secret_number)

    def guess_the_number (self, the_secret_number) :
        still_playing = True
        while still_playing == True :
            answer = int (input ('Take a guess : '))
            if answer == the_secret_number :
                print ('That is exactly correct! You win!')
                still_playing = False
            else :
                if answer > the_secret_number :
                    print ('Sorry, you are too high.')
                if answer < the_secret_number :
                    print ('Sorry, you are too low.')
        if self.play_again () == True :
            self.start_the_game ()

    def play_again (self) :
        self.difficulty = self.difficulty * 2
        answer = input ('Would you like to play again? ')
        if answer [0].lower () == 'y' : return True
        return False

users_name = input ('Please enter your name : ')
my_game = Guessing_Game (users_name)
```